# How can I modify my loop to make it run quicker?

Tags: python, loops, numpy, for-loop

I am tasked with running this loop 100,000 times in order to get the value of a man's investment portfolio after 25 years. When I try to run this code my computer keeps freezing. When I try to run it 10 times its smooth, 1000 times smooth, but anything above 10,000 it freezes. Do you guys have any suggestions on how I can modify my code?

```
def InvestmentSim():
    mu = 0.076 ###Mean
    sigma = 0.167 ###Standard deviation
    np.exp(np.random.normal(mu, sigma,))


    u = .076 ###set variables 
    bi = 50000 ###set variables 

    empty = [] ###empty list
    for i in range(25): ###range for birthdays 40-65
        bi = ((bi) * (np.exp(np.random.normal(mu, sigma))))
        empty.append(bi)

    roundedempty = [ '%.2f' % elem for elem in empty ]
    age = [41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,
                   60,61,62,63,64,65]
    len(age) ##making sure my lists match up
    investing = pd.DataFrame({"Balance":roundedempty, "Age":age})
    investing.set_index('Age', inplace=True)
    a = investing.iloc[24]['Balance']
    a = float(investing.iloc[24]['Balance'])
    return a

def AverageSim(iterations):
    results = []
    for n in range (0, iterations):
        a = InvestmentSim()
        results.append(a)
        print(results)
    return results
AverageSim(100000)

myresult = AverageSim(100000)
myresults = np.array(myresult) # Turn the list of values into an array
mean = np.mean(myresults)
median = np.median(myresults)
print(mean, median)
```

Comment: This is better posted on the code review SE.

Comment: Whats that? Sorry noob here.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks! Is that the best place to go? Whats the difference between normal stack?

Comment: you could use an empty np.array and fill that by assigning results with index instead of appending to list for your results in AverageSim. Large lists are always slow, and appending on large lists is typically not a good idea performance wise.

Comment: @ahed87 can you enlighten me with some sample code?

Comment: results = np.zeros((nbr_sims,)) then in your loop do results[n] = a; also why do you even have print statements in a loop, that for sure makes it slow, especially since you print the total result list rather than just the iteration outcome. You can also find self help in [profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html?highlight=profile) your code.

Comment: What is nbr_sims?

Comment: @ahed87 by nbr_sims do you mean AverageSim?

Comment: Is this your real code here `AverageSim(100000) myresult = AverageSim(100000)` or a mistake from copying it into SO? You call the same function twice and throw away the result of the first run.

Comment: @Piinthesky ya thats my real code

Comment: @Piinthesky sorry still learning code everyday, it doesn't come easy to me. Since I wanted to work with the values outside of the simulations I thought I would have to save it like that.

Comment: Then you run the simulation twice and only store the result the second time.

Comment: nbr_sims is same as your `iterations` in the AverageSim fcn.

Comment: @Piinthesky if I wanted to append a list of just the balances over $300,000 how would I do that?